# How to make a serialized column empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a column in Company, that is serialized as Array:

```
class Company
  serialize :column_name, Array
end
```

In **rails console**, when I try the following:

```
existing = Company.last.column_name
# it gives a array with single element, say [1]
existing.delete(1)
# now existing is []
Company.last.update_attributes!(column_name: existing)
# It empties the array, so:
Company.last.column_name #gives []
```

But, when I try the same code in `remove` method of some controller, it never removes the last element. It always returns [1].

**How can I empty the serialized column?**

**NOTE:-** This logic works when I have multiple elements, but doesn't work for the last element alone.

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
def remove_restricted_num
  company = Company.where(id: params[:id]).first
  restricted_numbers = company.restricted_numbers
  num = params[:num].to_i

  if restricted_numbers.include?(num)
    restricted_numbers.delete(num)
    company.update_attributes!(restricted_numbers: restricted_numbers)

    render js: "alert('#{num} was removed')"
  else
    render js: "alert('Number not found in the list')"
  end
end
```

Comment: Why don't you just update your column like this : `company.column_name = []; company.save` ?

Comment: @Stefan Sorry for the typo. I corrected it. It's `delete`.

Comment: Could you show your controller's actual `remove` method? It doesn't make much sense that some code works in `rails console` but not in your controller.

Comment: @Stefan I have added the controller code without `dup`

Comment: How does the code behave when trying to remove the last item? Does it render "... was removed" without actually removing it?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, it renders without deleting it, as I don't check if it was really removed. And uopn page refresh I again see the `num` in UI.

Comment: How does the corresponding database query look like in you logs?

Comment: When it's from controller, it only loads the company(SELECT company*...), but, there is no update query

Comment: I've just set up a test application with Rails 4.2 and your code works just fine for me. Must be something else.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for trying out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the fix, we need to use `dup` to get a independent variable `existing`, which otherwise was referencing `Company.last.column_name`

```
existing = Company.last.column_name.dup # THIS WORKS!!!
existing.delete(1)
Company.last.update_attributes!(column_name: existing)
```

This updates the column to `[]`, as I need.

Comment: This is probably related to ActiveRecord's "dirty" tracking. Doing in-place modifications on strings, arrays, or other data structures often leaves ActiveRecord thinking that nothing has changed, no object references were swapped out. Whenever possible do straight reassignment.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me.
`c = Company.last`
`existing = c.column_name.del(1)`
`c.column_name = existing`
`c.save!`

Comment: That's the same object: `existing.object_id` does not change. You need to introduce a new object. Your `dup` solution does that, but `c.column_name = [ ]` is the better way to do it if you're intending that value to be cleared. It makes it much more obvious to someone reading the code that's your intent.

Comment: @tadman I get it what you are saying, and that's correct!! But, the only thing that was stopping me was to have a generic code. What I mean is, the logic worked if there were more elements, but only for last element I didn't wanted to go with separate condition check like: `if existing.present? ? existing : []`

Comment: @tadman if dirty tracking _was_ broken, it wouldn't work in any case, i.e. neither when removing the second to last item, nor in rails console.

Comment: @Stefan It's not broken so much as unable to track differences when you do in-place modifications. The old value and the new value are the same object, so they're always identical. Assigning a new object means they can differ.

Comment: @tadman my point is that if ActiveModel::Dirty couldn't track in-place modification (in can), the OP's code wouldn't work at all. It wouldn't work for deleting `2` from `[1,2]` and it wouldn't work in rails console.